# Google People API: member_resource_names from not empty contact group returns nil

Tags: ruby, google-people-api

According to the [documentation in the code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/d3b9abfbb2f5d7d2b40df24c802296217f67cbb1/generated/google/apis/people_v1/classes.rb#L354-L360), `member_resource_names` should return a "list of contact person resource names that are members of the contact group", but it's returning nil.

I'm doing something like this (ruby):

```
service = Google::Apis::PeopleV1::PeopleServiceService.new
# authentication code
contact_group = service.get_contact_group("contactGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
=> #<Google::Apis::PeopleV1::ContactGroup:0x00007fd69fca6f48
  @etag="xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  @formatted_name="Contact list",
  @group_type="USER_CONTACT_GROUP",
  @member_count=10,
  @metadata=#<...>,
  @name="Contact list",
  @resource_name="contactGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
contact_group.member_resource_names
=> nil
```

Even though the `member_count` is 10, `member_resource_names` returns nil all the time.

I'm using ruby 2.4, and google gem 0.52.0.

Anyone else has seen this issue?

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

When calling [contactGroups.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/get), you should specify `maxMembers`.

#### Explanation:

If you visit the official API documentation regarding [contactGroups](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups), you'll see that `memberResourceNames` is only populated in certain circumstances:

> **memberResourceNames[]**: Output only. The list of contact person resource names that are members of the contact group. The field is only populated for GET requests and **will only return as many members as maxMembers in the get request**.

`maxMembers`, though, if not specified, [defaults to 0](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/get#query-parameters):

> **maxMembers**: Optional. Specifies the maximum number of members to return. **Defaults to 0 if not set, which will return zero members**.

#### Solution:

Therefore, based on the library sample:

```
def get_contact_group(resource_name, max_members: nil, fields: nil, quota_user: nil, options: nil, &block)
```

You should change this line:

```
contact_group = service.get_contact_group("contactGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

With something similar to this:

```
contact_group = service.get_contact_group("contactGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 100)
```

Where `100` is the maximum number of members to return (change it according to your preferences).

#### Reference:

- [Google API Ruby Client: people_v1 / service.rb](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/d3b9abfbb2f5d7d2b40df24c802296217f67cbb1/generated/google/apis/people_v1/service.rb)